# Alerts for apps failing Marathon healthchecks

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, health-monitoring, alerts

I've been configuring http healthchecks for all my apps in marathon which are working nicely, the trouble is marathon will keep stepping in and restarting a container failing it's healthcheck and I won't know unless I happen to be looking in the Marathon UI.

Is there a way to retrieve all apps that have a failed healthcheck so I can send an email alert or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marathon exposes information about failing healthcheck with [event bus](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html) so you can write a simple service that will consume Marathons HealthChecks Event (`"eventType": "instance_health_changed_event"`) and translate it to metric, alert you name it.

For a reference I can recommend [allegro/appcop](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-appcop#how-it-works). This is the service that scales down unhealthy applications. Its code could be easily altered to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I had written code which called the marathon api's on a schedule, i wasn't aware of this event bus